# Some problem with encoding $_GET variable from address bar

Tags: codeigniter, encoding, uri, urlencode

My project is based on CodeIgniter, but I guess this question isn't about it at all.

First, I have enabled query strings and a search function. Search string passes to the “searchterm” variable and when I pass it through the form, it works fine and looks like:

http:// local/home/search/?searchterm=testtesttest

Okay, now when I input some cyrillic string in a search form, it works fine as well, the URI would be for example:

http:// local/home/search/?searchterm=привет (in chrome) or
http:// local/home/search/?searchterm=������ (in IE, Opera etc.)

Two above cases work fine, BUT WHEN I enter the CYRILLIC search string directly from the address bar (for example, in Opera or IE) it doesn’t wanna search anything. $_GET[‘searchterm’] is empty, and as for QUERY_STRING, it is something like searchterm=������ (all data from profiler).

I urldecode my string from the controller, but it somehow doesn’t work. I also tried some iconv() cases, from what I’ve googled, but they also didn’t work.

So the question is why all other browsers except chrome doesn’t retrieve CYRILLIC $_GET variable from the address bar if it was entered from there? Passing through the form everything works fine.

Thanks in advance, guys. Hope for your help.

P.S.
I've also found:

%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE

- this is passed from the form, accept-charset is set to UTF-8. In that case, as I said, everything works fine. And:

%ED%E0%F7%E0%EB%EE

- this comes in the address bar when typing the string directly inside the address bar. So I guess every browser changes my cyrillic symbols into something strange... I don't know :(

Don't forget that with Chrome everything works fine! Maybe it's because by default this browser doesn't encode cyrillic symbols in wrong way like other browsers.

Comment: why not make your life ten times easier and just use post instead of get?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing part of the issue here is that you are using UTF-8 characters in the URL ... You can setup PHP to use UTF-8 by default from within the php.ini file or by adding `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');` somewhere in your application, (I add it to the root index.php file within CodeIgniter if I can't modify the .ini file).

I tested both Japanese and your example in Firefox and Safari quickly and they both displayed the correct strings. More information about setting up Apache/PHP for UTF-8 can be found in [this excellent guide](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html#fixcharset-server).